# wsl: запуск нескольких отдельных экземпляров Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, wsl

Уважаемые господа,

я экспериментирую с написанием простеньких сетевых программ, и для тестирования мне нужно запустить под Windows 10 (версия 20H2) несколько отдельных экземпляров Ubuntu под wsl2. Смысл в  том, чтобы у программ были отдельные файловые системы и отдельные сетевые адреса (по умолчанию wsl использует nat, так что адреса получаются вида 172.17.106.xx)

Я [прочитал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584765/how-do-you-install-multiple-separate-instances-of-ubuntu-in-wsl), что для этого нужно "экспортировать и импортировать опять" дистрибутив:

```
wsl --list --all          - вижу список дистрибутивов
wsl --export Ubuntu-20.04 ubuntu.tar
wsl --import Ubuntu_2 .\Ubuntu_2 ubuntu.tar
```

После этого я вижу в списке дистрибутивов второй дистрибутив Ubuntu_2. Он запускается (командой `wsl -d Ubuntu_2`). Но сеть у него ровно та же самая, что и у первого. То есть, ifconfig показывает у них одинаковые настройки сети.

Поскольку диск у них "разделяемый" (то есть, все пользовательские файлы, например, лежат в `/home/konst/`), то я вообще не особо понимаю, как это работает. Видимо, у этих дистрибутивов разные "списки запущенных процессов" - по крайней мере, ps говорит о том, что в разных запущеных дистрибутивах bash имеет разные pid.

Но почему у них одинаковая сеть? и самое главное - как её сделать с разными IP адресами?

Я набрёл вот на такую [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config), в которой есть раздел "Configure per distro launch settings with wslconf", но по той короткой инфе, которая есть, я не понял, можно ли настроить им разные сетевые адреса.

Не сталкивались ли Вы с такой проблемой? Буду благодарен за советы.

PS. Можнор было бы перейти на "честные виртуальные машины", но мой комп не такой мощный, да и городить огород с полноценными VM неохота.

Comment: офтоп: `но мой комп не такой мощный` — может быть, настало самое время заменить операционную систему на менее прожорливую? gnu/linux, например. сразу разрешится, кстати, и описываемая в вопросе проблема.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin - спасибо за совет и за Ваши другие ответы. я пробовал, есть несколько мелких проблем, котрые в Ubuntu портят жизнь начинающему. Но, мне кажется, я в своей винде поганой уже не так далеко: Msys2, замена стандартной командной строки на cmder, VS code, WSL2... от винды остались: шрифты, привычное переключение русский-английский по Ctrl+shift (ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194158), копирование - вставка по ctrl+c-ctrl+v. А так - я с вами :-)

Comment: Нашел на английском SO подобный вопрос, и тоже нет ответа... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629535/how-can-i-have-different-ip-for-differnt-distrubutions-on-wsl2

Answer (score 2):

Самый верный способ: поставить разные версии убунту на виндовс. Например 20.04, 16, и т.д и т.п.
В системе wsl2 они отобразятся как отдельные системы, каждый со своим адресом и своей файловой системой.
Что же насчет IP адресов и прочее, это разумеется имеет прямую связь с вашей основной системой - виндоус. Как там настроен IP так и будет на вашей убунту.

Comment: Круто! Такое простое решение не пришло мне в голову! Сегодня же попробую! Хотя, я подумал, можно же создать несколько docker - контейнеров и запускаться в них интерактивно - и тогда у них будут разные адреса внутри wsl2

Comment: докер контейнер это одно, а подсистема wsl2 это совсем другое. запуская в докере, надо понимать что он полностью изолированный и надо настраивать докер файл

Comment: Мне очень жаль, но при установке разных версий убунту на wsl Вы получите две линуксовые системы с разными файловыми системами и одним и тем же IP адресом. Так что вопрос остаётся открытым

Answer (score 0):

Я немного поэкспериментировал.

В WSL, похоже, эта проблема не решается.

Даже при установке разных версий убунту на wsl Вы получите две линуксовые системы с разными файловыми системами и одним и тем же IP адресом.

Есть ишью с просьбой сделать такую возможность в wsl, но никакого прогресса на эту тему пока нет.

При установке докер-образа убунты командой вроде `docker run -it ubuntu` мы получаем линукс с отдельным ip, но роутинга между ним и wsl-ем - нет.

Спасает только установка двух докер - образов убунты и перенос работы с сетью в них. Тогда - всё получается! Образы получают разные (последовательные) ip адреса в сети докера (172.17.0.xxx)